# How can I improve my expression including an aggregate-function?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, aggregate

I have a polygon layer and a point layer ("wka"). I want to count the points in each polygon. I know I could do it with the following tools: "count points in polygon" or "join attributes by location". This works, but the disadvantage is the geodata management I have to do: save in a new location, import in the project, copy the styles form the old polygon layer to the new, etc.

I found out I can use the aggregate function in the field calculator. I tried that expression and it surprisingly works :)

```
aggregate(layer:= 'wka', aggregate:='count',
expression:="fid", filter:=contains(geometry(@parent), $geometry))
```

I am wondering is there a "cleaner" way to write that expression? Does the part `expression:="fid",` make any sense? I could write any attribute name for "fid" and it still works. But when I delete this part from the expression, the expression doesn't work anymore. I am wondering why.

Comment: Since you are counting it does not really matter which field you use, the field just shouldnt be NULL. You could also use $id for example.

Comment: The expression:=$id works! But I can't delete that part of the expression, right? I have to leave it in the expression if I understand you right.

Comment: The aggregate expression does need the 3 first argument to work. Your expression would be used for every features that match your filter. You can replace it by `expression:=1` and it will work still. if you have nothing the function will not know what to count.

Comment: I see, thank you very much!!

Comment: yes, otherwise you would count nothing